# Bad window path name when assigning labelwidget

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create a class to build a labelframe where the labelwidget option is an entry widget. The Widget classes are in a different file to the calling script.

I an getting an error when trying to associate the entry widget with the labelewidget option of the labelframe.

This is the error message:

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name "<RtMaintWidgets.Entry object at 0x0000000003768080>"
```

This is the code for the calling script:

```
# Create the frame
    # self.FSrootF = rt.Frame.crt(self.FSwindow)
    self.FSrootF = tk.Frame(self.FSwindow)
    self.FSrootF.grid(sticky='nsew')

    # Create the widgets
    self.FScrtInfo()

def FScrtInfo(self):
    """
    """
    # Create the label frame
    # " User Information:"
    # "rasterToolGUI allows you to adjust \\n
    #  spot elevations in X_Plane scenery.\\n
    #  Select the file on which to work,\\n
    #  select the options and let the magic begin."
    self.FSinfoLf = rt.LabelFrame(self.FSrootF,
                                  self.FSparms['LF001'])
    self.FSinfoLf.grid()
```

..and this is the code in the widgets script

```
class Entry(object):
    def __init__(self, into, text, justify='left'):
        """

        :param into: 
        :param text: 
        :param justify: 
        """
        self.__into = into
        self.__text = text
        self.__titlewidth = len(self.__text) + 3
        self.__justify = justify
        self.__entrysvar = tk.StringVar()

        self.__entrysvar.set(self.__text)
        self.__entry = tk.Entry(self.__into,
                                width=self.__titlewidth,
                                textvariable=self.__entrysvar,
                                justify=self.__justify)


class LabelFrame(object):
    " Class documentation"
    def __init__(self, into, title, labelanchor='nw', relief='groove'):
        """

        :param into:
        :param title:
        :param labelanchor:
        :param relief:
        """
        self.__into = into
        self.__title = ' ' + title
        self.__labelanchor = labelanchor
        self.__relief = relief

        # Create the lf
        self.__lf = tk.LabelFrame(self.__into,
                                  labelanchor=self.__labelanchor,
                                  relief=self.__relief)
        # create the entry
        self.__entry = Entry(self.__lf,
                             self.__title)

        self.__lf['labelwidget'] = self.__entry   < Statement causing the error
```

I thought I knew what I was doing, but apparently not. I have tried changing the "self", and changing the syntax of the call, but I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.

In testing, the python assigned names do seem to transfer into widgets script so I cannot see what the actual error is.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can I add a new issue to this same situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `labelwidget` must be set to an actual widget. You are setting it to one of your custom classes which *contains* a widget but which isn't itself a widget.

Comment: Thank you so much Bryan.